# How to have different css configuration for <kbd> tag

Tags: html, css

In a grails project, I have a css like below to overwrite the default kbd config

```
.tool-preview kbd {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: right;
```

and a gsp like

```
<div class="custom-indicators-row-one">
    <div class="indicator-1 pull-left" >
        <kbd></kbd>
    </div>

    <div class="indicator-2 pull-right" >
        <kbd></kbd>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a javascript which will populate value for kbd tag. Let say I want to have different width for value under `div class="indicator-1 pull-left"` and `div class="indicator-2 pull-right"`, how can this be done? Currently any width changes to the kbd css will impact both of those div in the gsp which have kbd.

Answer (score 1):

you can write your css something like this

```
.indicator1 kbd{
/*your css*/
width: 300px;
}

.indicator2 kbd{
/*your css*/
width: 400px;
}
```

that will work for you i guess.